# Is there a complete list of Catholic Saints somewhere online?

Tags: catholicism, saint, resource-request

I'd like to find a list of Catholic Saints who names end in "bert".  IF we have a boy, I'd like my next child to be named "...bert" Keith Turner after his uncle Keith and potential saint GKC and I'm looking for the most wondrous Northumbrian names to annoy my wife with daily until she finally gives in (or has the baby and names him John).

If a complete list of Saint names, I could grep it for those ending in bert and get my desired list.

Comment: Find an online list, [like this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Catholic_saints).  Hit Ctrl-F.  Enter "bert " (note the space at the end).  Work through the results.  The Wikipedia list gives 10 individuals, most of whom have "bert" at the end of their first name.

Comment: http://www.catholic.org/saints/stindex.php?lst=E

Comment: @kris that's better than the wiki for sure!

Comment: Actually that's really strange, there are a few *bert's on the wiki list who aren't on the all-encompassing catholic.org list.  And cuthbert is nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 4):

**Is there a complete list of Catholic Saints somewhere online?**

The Roman Martyrology is probably your best bet.

The following website is the most complete source of Catholic saints I know to exist: [Catholic Saints Info.](http://catholicsaints.info/alphabetical-list/) Not only is this site constantly being updated, but it also show the reader other sources of information, variations of saints' name, but it even shows particular (local) feasts of saints such as translations, if applicable.

The ultimate "List of Saints" from Rome can be found in this book which is published by the Congregation for the Causes of Saints: **[Index Causarum Sanctorum ac Beatorum](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/631186293).** Unfortunately it exists only in book form and only very few Catholic libraries or Religious Institutions possess a copy. It gets updated every so often, but not yearly.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I got more bert's out of it because some of the ones I was looking for were "berth's" instead and it put the other variations of their names.    Guessing I'd have to screen scrape to excess to find out that St. Gumbert is St. Gondebert.

Comment: Hi Ken. Being interested in such database, I got access to a copy of the book "Index Causarum ..." in my university library, but it only contains records for saints from the 16th century onwards. And also, it does not contain all of them, as I found there were several missing, particularly martyrs. Have you seen the book yourself? Maybe I got a different version? This was from 1953.

Comment: @luchonacho Yes , I  have seen a more updated one. I believe it to be a 1985 version. I found it quite complete, but I am sure some obscure saints may be missing. The one I read started in the 12 century.

Comment: See my answer, that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Looking myself for a **complete** list of Catholic Saints (including martyrs), I got access to a 1953's version of the *Index Causarum Sanctorum ac Beatorum* that Ken suggested, but I found that it is incomplete, as some saints are missing and the earlier saints are from the 16th century ([Ken says](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48037/is-there-a-complete-list-of-catholic-saints-somewhere-online/48046#comment162411_48046) a more recent version contains saints from the 12th century onward).

However, I found some earlier texts which do contain saints since the first century. These are actually rather "famous" books, as they are not only indexes but contain descriptions of the lives of saints too.

The first one and perhaps most complete is the [*Acta Santorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acta_Sanctorum), a 68 volume compilation of saints! This is available online as PDF, and also as [searchable text](http://acta.chadwyck.co.uk/). The latter requires a subscription though (I got access through my university library, so confirm it works).

The second one is the [*The Lives of the Fathers, Martyrs and Other Principal Saints*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alban_Butler#The_Lives_of_Saints), by Alban Butler. This is a 12 volume compilation that has been updated more recently. It is also available online, both as PDF and [searchable text](http://www.bartleby.com/210/), including a [list of all saints covered](http://www.bartleby.com/210/index2.html).

For example, looking at the last one, you get:

```
Adalbert
Adelbert
Aglibert
Albert
Ansbert
Aubert
Cuthbert
Eadbert
Ethelbert
Gilbert
Hubert
Humbert
John Gualbert
Lambert
Norbert
Radbert
Philibert
Rembert
Rigobert
Robert
Sigebert
Swibert or Swidbert
Wigbert
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Nathaniel for the clue, I didn't think they had one page with all those Saints (it's not complete though).

[List of Catholic saints (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Catholic_saints) yields:

```
Adalbert
Albert
Angilbert
Fitzherbert
Gualbert
Heribert
Imbert
Norbert
Radbert
Robert
```

This will definitely help...

---

But there's an even better list of saints over at catholic.org

unfortunately I've got to screen scrap a bit more so I wrote a script

```
#!/bin/bash
for letter in {A..Z}
do
  for number in {1..5}
  do
    curl -o $letter-$number -s http://www.catholic.org/saints/stindex.php?lst=$letter&page=$number
  done
done
```

and grepping all that output yields:

```
Agilbert
Aibert
Albert
Augebert
Dagobert
Eadbert
Edbert
Egbert
Emebert
Engelbert
Erembert
Ethelbert
Floribert
Fontcubert
Frodobert
Fulbert
Fymbert
Gamelbert
Gaulbert
Gilbert
Godebert
Gondebert
Gosbert
Gumbert
Gundebert
Herbert
Heribert
Hildebert
Hubert
Humbert
Imbert
Jambert
Joubert
Lambert
Libert
Madalbert
Norbert
Philibert
Radbert
Rambert
Rembert
Ribert
Rigobert
Ritbert
Robert
Suitbert
Tilbert
Ubert
Walbert
Waldebert
Wigbert
```

But Cuthbert is still mysteriously missing.

---

Finally (hopefully, unless an online index is produced), Mr. Ken Graham has provided catholicsaints.info and screen-scraping that site with:

```
#!/bin/bash
for letter in {a..z}
do
  curl -o "$letter-info" -s http://catholicsaints.info/saints-$letter/
done
```

and grepping it:

```
cat *-info | grep -o -e "[A-Za-z]*bert" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort | uniq
```

provides:

```
adalbert
agilbert
aibert
albert
angilbert
ansbert
aribert
aubert
augebert
austrebert
autbert
bert
cuthbert
dagobert
dealbert
eadbert
edbert
edilbert
egbert
ekbert
emebert
engelbert
erembert
ethelbert
fitzherbert
fridebert
frithbert
frodobert
gamelbert
garembert
gilbert
gobert
godebert
gosbert
gualbert
guibert
gundebert
herbert
heribert
hildebert
hrodbert
hubert
hugbert
humbert
imbert
jambert
josbert
lambert
landebert
libert
madalbert
norbert
philibert
radbert
ragnobert
rembert
ribert
rigobert
rimbert
robert
sigebert
simbert
sintbert
suidbert
suitbert
swidbert
switbert
swithbert
trudbert
ubert
valbebert
walembert
wigbert
```

Comment: No [Cuthbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthbert)?

Comment: @bruisedreed need to figure out a way to screenscrape the oxford dictionary of saints index..  That would be a good list...

Comment: Gotta go with Egbert

Answer (score 0):

[Glaubenszeugen](http://www.glaubenszeugen.de/tage/jan/01.htm) (translation: Witnesses of Faith)

This is the most complete list of saints I have
ever seen on the internet. The page I tagged will show all saints who have a feast day on January 1. You can start from here and search for saints by their feast days. Included in this website are Venerables.